# GLM with multiple imputation or mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, spss

I have a data set with repeated measures with two treatment groups where each subject is measured at 3 time points.But the data set includes missing data. In SPSS if I use `general linear model` it ignores the rows with missing data therefore I am left with very few data. As this is a issue I read that `Mixed Model` approach can handle this missing data issue better.  But can I use General Linear Model with multiple imputation instead of using General Linear Model?
Because General Linear Model allows me to do plots for the two groups over time and it also shows the interactioj between time and groups(time*groups) which I don't know how to do in mixed model

Answer (score 4):

Besides getting the correlation structure right as @Peter Flom stated,  with missing records in longitudinal data, other than baseline data (used to adjust for covariates) the recommendations are to use all available data in a full maximum likelihood setting.  There are basically three types of models satisfying this recommendation: generalized least squares (used to be called growth curve models), mixed effects models, and Bayesian hierarchical models.  Any model that fully specifies the multivariate distribution of repeated measurements is probably OK, if it fits.  Full models are the most robust methods to non-random missing data (e.g., non-random dropouts).  GEE is not robust to such missing data.

Answer (score 3):

A multilevel model is used to deal with the dependence of the data.  Multiple imputation does not deal with that. So, you need an MLM (or GEE, or perhaps some other method that deals with the dependence).